# Group transactions on a single row

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Suppose I have the following dataset containing transactional data.  Subset below for illustration purposes:

```
BillName    Item Number
Customer A  477565
Customer A  8400212
Customer A  8400213
Customer A  461230
Customer A  461240
Customer A  477545
Customer A  8657915
Customer B  672050
Customer B  892223
Customer C  640741
Customer C  640772
Customer C  640660
```

How do I transform it to look like the following using Excel or SQL Server?

```
Customer A  477565  8400212 8400213 461230  461240  477545  8657915
Customer B  672050  892223                  
Customer C  640741  640772  640660
```

Comment: What DBMS?  MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

In excel, add another row to show the order of the entries and create a pivot table:

BillName    group   Item Number precedence

```
BillName    group   Item Number precedence
Customer    A   477565  1
Customer    A   8400212 2
Customer    A   8400213 3
Customer    A   461230  4
Customer    A   461240  5
Customer    A   477545  6
Customer    A   8657915 7
Customer    B   672050  1
Customer    B   892223  2
Customer    C   640741  1
Customer    C   640772  2
Customer    C   640660  3
```

Create a pivot table that looks like this:

[image]

or in tabluar form repeating all labels
[image]

**EDIT:** For SQL, look into the Pivot relational operator to do this kind of thing.

Comment: This is a good idea, but the data set is too large.  I'll give it a go in MS SQL Server

Comment: @user1765523 you didn't state that in the question.  Why did you ask for it in excel, if that was a non-option?  I answered as per your question: 'How do I transform it to look like the following using Excel...'

Comment: The dataset is in Excel and runs fine.  I didn't know what the max combinations would be and had know idea that I'd reach the limit of columns using the pivot table approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution by @ivan7707 is the way to go.  It leverages the power of Excel, and you can even bring the dataset in via MS Query.

That said, if you're looking for a brute-force solution, you could always to something like this in VBA:

```
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim bill, item, priorBill As String
Dim row, col As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Conn.Open "Your Connection String"
Set rs = Conn.Execute("select bill_name, item_number from bills order by 1")

row = 1
col = 2

Do While Not rs.EOF
  bill = rs.Fields(0).Value
  item = rs.Fields(1).Value

  If bill <> priorBill Then
    row = row + 1
    col = 2

    ws.Cells(row, 1).Value = bill
    priorBill = bill
  End If

  ws.Cells(row, col).Value = item
  col = col + 1

  rs.MoveNext
Loop

Conn.Close
```

Results:

[image]